# arithmetic on bash function return value without accessing $?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a green hand for shell scripting.

I wonder can we do something like this:

```
a=$((func arg))
```

to have it mean:

```
func arg
a=$?
```

I am struggling to understand what kind of arithmetic can we put on function return value?

Is function return value an expression of int type?

I see people do `! func arg`. Why `!func arg` doesn't work? Aside from `!`, what other operation can be used in this way? I am especially interested in comparison operator.

How to do something like this in one liner?

```
if [ (fun arg) -eq some_random_int_literal]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's anything that automatically substitutes `$?` into a command. It's not that common that you care about the specific value of `$?`, all that usually matters is if it's 0 (success) or non-0 (error).

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what the return value is. It's intended to be an error indication (0=no error, nonzero=there was an error), so doing math on it doesn't really make sense. Please don't try to use it for something other than success/failure, that never works very well.

Comment: if `func arg` returns a `1` ... how would you tell if this is an actual `'value'` or an `error/status`?  same goes for anything else returned by `func arg` ... `0` => value or `'success'`? `2` => value or an `error/status`?

Comment: @markp-fuso The return status is always a success/failure indication. Usually, if a function needs to return some sort of data value, it'll print it (i.e. send it to standard output), and the caller will capture that with `$( )`, as in `result=$(function argument argument...)`

Comment: @GordonDavisson I can override the functions's return status with the `return` command, consider: `mf() { echo 'abc'; return 39; }; x=$(mf); echo "$x:$?"` => `abc:39`; while the function did execute successfully the return status is no longer 0/success

Comment: @markp-fuso I wouldn't call that "overriding", just reporting an error when nothing actually went wrong. Return statuses don't (usually) happen automatically, it's up to the function's author to make sure it reports errors accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing I know of that will automatically substitute `$?`, so you have to use it explicitly if you care about the specific value, not just whether it's zero or non-zero.

The simplest way I can see to write what you want is:

```
if [ $(fun arg >/dev/null; echo $?) -eq some_random_int_literal ]
```

You can leave out the redirection to `/dev/null` if you know the function doesn't produce output on stdout.